# Cleanest way of joining depending on a parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQL 5.7 and I have a complex query with some parameters which are optional to filter.
And the join depends on whether the parameter comes or not. I think the summary would be: If there is a parameter then join (inner) else ignore the join.

I've simplified the example and I get this with the following fragments:

```
SELECT * 
FROM commerce cm, commerce_tags cmt
WHERE (? is null or cmt.tag_id = ?) AND 
(? is null or cmt.commerce_id = cm.id)
```

Or in other syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM commerce cm
INNER JOIN commerce_tags cmt ON  (? is null or cmt.tag_id = ?) AND (? is null or cmt.commerce_id = cm.id)
```

Is there a cleaner and (more efficient) way to do this? Maybe I'm complicating my life...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

I think you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM commerce cm LEFT JOIN
     commerce_tags cmt
     ON cmt.commerce_id = cm.id AND ? is not null
WHERE (? is null or cmt.tag_id = ?);
```

If the first parameter is not null, then the `join` is not run.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gordon